# How to fix? Chrome console : ERR_UNSAFE_REDIRECT

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

**Post request webserver to the nodejs backend:**

---

```
     $('#login').click(function() {
        $.post(
            '/login',
            {
                mail: encodeURIComponent($('#mail').val()),
                password: encodeURIComponent($('#password').val())
            },
            function(result) {
                console.log(result);
            });
    });
```

**Problem**

---

The backend get successfull the post request, but the redirect to the new page will not happen cause I´ve in the chrome console this error:

> POST http://localhost:1000/login net::ERR_UNSAFE_REDIRECT

I know this is not a protected SSL connection. But is there a way to fix it? Or did I made some settings wrong?

**Code I´ve in the backend:**

---

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
   console.log(req.body);
   res.redirect(__dirname+'/wwwroot/views/profile/dashboard.html');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sending a redirect response to ajax request, why not just let javascript do the redirect for you by using `window.location.href`:

Server:

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.json({ success: true });
});
```

Client:

```
$('#login').click(function() {
    $.post(
        '/login',
        {
            mail: encodeURIComponent($('#mail').val()),
            password: encodeURIComponent($('#password').val())
        },
        function(result) {
            if (result.success) {
                window.location.href = '/dashboard'
            }
        });
});
```

Note that you should define `/dashboard` route if you want the example above  works:

```
app.get('/dashboard', function(req, res) {
    ...
});
```